# Numerical SDE Simulation for non-Gaussian?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

Assume that we have SDE:

\begin{align}
dX_t = a(X_t)dt+b(X_t)dBt
\end{align}

where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

For numerical simulation, we could try

\begin{align}
X_{k+1}^{\Delta t} = a(X_k^{\Delta t})dt+\sqrt{\Delta t}b(X_k^{\Delta t})dB_t
\end{align}

However, my question is whether that simulation will work even if we have a different distribution instead of $B_t$ ~ $N(0,1)$

I tested with (case 1: standard normal distribution) & (case 2: standard uniform distribution), but the result seems to be similar...

Maybe I made a mistake in my code, but does any independent standard non-normal distribution simulation still work theoretically??

Comment: Maybe the result is similar because of the central limit theorem? IMO what you describe should work

Comment: @kevinkayaks oh wait..! Yes maybe I thought too much!